# Using Redis to Keep Track of Page Views from Incoming Traffic

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis

I'm trying to use Redis to keep track of page views so I can figure out which pages get the most views from incoming traffic (rather than from browsing within the site). However, right now when I check the quote ID in Redis, the value being returned is nil. I've added both to routes.rb. Thanks!

Here's the Javascript I'm using:

```
    function viewCount(quote_id) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"PUT",
            url:"/quotes/" + quote_id + "/viewed",
            contentType:"json"
        });
    }

    function quoteReferrer(quote_id){
        if ((document.referrer != null) && (location.hostname !=(document.referrer.split('/')[2])))
        {
            $.ajax({
                type:"PUT",
                url:"/quotes/" + quote_id + "/referred",
                contentType:"json"
            })
        }
    }
```

The Ruby controller code:

```
      def viewed
        REDIS.incr("quote_id_#{params[:id]}_viewed_count")
        puts params[:id]

        respond_to do |format|
          format.json { head :ok }
        end
      end

      def referred
        REDIS.incr("quote_id_#{params[:id]}_referred")
        puts params[:id]

        respond_to do |format|
          format.json { head :ok }
        end
      end
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your REDIS calls *(assuming your connection is working)*. Have you checked the response of the Ajax request? You can check this in your browser's console, under the 'Networking' tab *(at least in Chrome; Firefox is similar)*.

Comment: Do you define the appropriate routes?

Comment: You might check out Google Analytics if you just want information about your site visitors.

Comment: "KEYS quote_id_*" returns something or not?